# Block with float when scrolling down and up

Tags: javascript, css, block, move

I am talking about the left block with adsense on this site: http://www.smejemsa.sk/obrazky/blondinka-v-autoskole/.
`position: fixed` in this case is not good a choice or I don't know how write to this in CSS.
3 `display: inline-block;` `position: relative` on the first two and `position: absolute` on the last.

I use this javascript to move the left block with ad - but there is a problem with faster scrolling.
When I scroll faster, the block's positions gets adjusted randomly. Any ideas?
I'm open for writing this with `position: fixed`, but I don't know how.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var pomocna=$(document).scrollTop();
    var vyska=pomocna-315;
    var skrol=$('#content-wrapper').height();

    if ((pomocna <= (skrol-380)) && (pomocna>=310))
        $('#ad-left').css('top',vyska);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var $left = $('.left-part'),
    leftOff = $left.offset().top,
    leftHeight = $left.height(),
    rightHeight = $('.right-part').height(),
    bottomAlign = rightHeight - leftHeight + leftOff;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var winScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(winScroll >= leftOff && winScroll < bottomAlign){
        $left.addClass('fixed').removeClass('bottom')
    }else if(winScroll >= bottomAlign){
        $left.removeClass('fixed').addClass('bottom')
    }
    else{
        $left.removeClass('fixed bottom')
    }
})
```

Since I don't like to use fixed numbers in the JS everything is calculated.

Here is a working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKZ3m/3/)

The important parts in the CSS are only this:

```
#content { position: relative;} 
.left-part { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
.left-part.fixed { position: fixed; left: auto; }
.left-part.bottom { top: auto; bottom: 0; }
```